# Loading specific column from .MAT file using another variable name

Tags: matlab

How can I load a specific set of data from a .mat file when I need to allow the user to specify which set to import?

For example:

```
a = 'setII'; % User specifies
db = matfile('example.mat');
model = db.a;
```

And this will read `a` as `'setII'` and then essentially load `db.setII`.

Currently it errors as it tries to look for a dataset labelled 'a'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dynamic field references:

```
model = db.(a)
```

which works if `a` is a string that contains the name of a field/property in `db`.

Example with a struct:

```
example = struct('name','test','values',[1 2 3 4], 'size', 4);
fieldname = 'values';
x = example.(fieldname)
```

returns

```
x = [1 2 3 4]
```